# Haskell: n queens ASCII graphic

Tags: haskell, ascii, n-queens

I've been working on the n queens problem on Haskell and I have been able to solve it for the most part.

```
queens :: Int -> [[Int]]
queens 0 = [[]]
queens n = [ x : y | y <- queens (n-1), x <- [1..8], safe x y 1]
     where
         safe x [] n = True
         safe x (y:ys) n = and [ x /= y , x /= y + n , x /= y - n , safe x ys (n+1)]
drawQueens :: [Int] -> String
drawQueens [] = ""
drawQueens x = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" ++ ['\n'] ++ concatMap showRow x  ++       ['\n']
    where
        size = length x
        spaces = replicate size '_' ++  ""
        showRow n = take (n - 1) spaces ++ "D" ++ take (size - n) spaces   ++ ['\n']
```

My second function, drawQueens, should ideally transform one solution to the queens problem to an ASCII graphic (see image below). My problems/questions are:

1. how do I get the queens function which outputs [[Int]] to "give" one [Int] to the drawQueens function?

2.Why isn't the compiler interpreting the ['\n']? How can I modify my code in order to achieve the desired output?

This was initially a homework question during the semester but I am now doing it just for myself.

[My desired output for n = 8](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znmeC.png)

[This is what my output of drawQueens looks like currently](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AB8Uh.png)

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compiler “interprets” `'\n'` just fine. Only, newlines aren't really “safe characters”, as in: you can't use a string literal with newlines in it directly in Haskell code. And the output of `print`, which GHCi uses by default to, well, print stuff, always tries to generate valid Haskell code, hence it escapes these newlines in again. This can be surpressed if you just instruct it to cat the string as it is to the terminal:

```
*Main> drawQueens [4,2,7,3,6,8,5,1]
"1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8\n___D____\n_D______\n______D_\n__D_____\n_____D__\n_______D\n____D___\nD_______\n\n"
*Main> putStrLn $ drawQueens [4,2,7,3,6,8,5,1]
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
___D____
_D______
______D_
__D_____
_____D__
_______D
____D___
D_______
```

There's still another problem: you don't have the same spacing in the number ow as in the actuall chessboard. Well, that's easily fixed too.

```
drawQueens :: [Int] -> String
drawQueens [] = ""
drawQueens x = "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8" ++ "\n" ++ concatMap showRow x
    where
        size = length x
        spaces n = concat $ replicate n "□ "
        showRow n = spaces (n - 1) ++ "♛ " ++ spaces (size - n) ++ "\n"
```

This then gives:

```
*Main> putStrLn $ drawQueens [4,2,7,3,6,8,5,1]
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8
□ □ □ ♛ □ □ □ □ 
□ ♛ □ □ □ □ □ □ 
□ □ □ □ □ □ ♛ □ 
□ □ ♛ □ □ □ □ □ 
□ □ □ □ □ ♛ □ □ 
□ □ □ □ □ □ □ ♛ 
□ □ □ □ ♛ □ □ □ 
♛ □ □ □ □ □ □ □
```

Fancy version:

```
chessboardRow, chessboardRow' :: [Maybe Char] -> String
chessboardRow' [] = "▌"
chessboardRow' (Just c:cs) = '▌':c:chessboardRow cs
chessboardRow' (Nothing:cs) = "▌ "++chessboardRow cs
chessboardRow [] = " "
chessboardRow (Just c:cs) = '▐':c:chessboardRow' cs
chessboardRow (Nothing:cs) = "▐█"++chessboardRow' cs

drawQueens :: [Int] -> String
drawQueens [] = ""
drawQueens x = "  a b c d e f g h" ++ "\n"
                 ++ concat (reverse $ 
                             zipWith3 showRow
                                      ['1'..]
                                      (cycle [chessboardRow, chessboardRow'])
                                      x)
                 ++ "\n"
    where
        size = length x
        showRow i rsh n = i : rsh (replicate (n - 1) Nothing
                                      ++ [Just '♛']
                                      ++ replicate (size - n) Nothing)
                              ++ "\n"
```

gives

```
  a b c d e f g h
8▌♛▐█▌ ▐█▌ ▐█▌ ▐█▌
7▐█▌ ▐█▌ ▐♛▌ ▐█▌  
6▌ ▐█▌ ▐█▌ ▐█▌ ▐♛▌
5▐█▌ ▐█▌ ▐█▌♛▐█▌  
4▌ ▐█▌♛▐█▌ ▐█▌ ▐█▌
3▐█▌ ▐█▌ ▐█▌ ▐♛▌  
2▌ ▐♛▌ ▐█▌ ▐█▌ ▐█▌
1▐█▌ ▐█▌♛▐█▌ ▐█▌
```

Comment: Thank you, I'll have a look at that right away.
And how do I get the vertical "1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8"?

Answer (score 1):

Giving ghci `drawQueens (head (queens 8))` will output a string that you can copypaste into code to get that string back, including quotes, literal \n etc.

Giving ghci `putStr (drawQueens (head (queens 8)))` will instead "interpret" the string, converting \n to newlines, omitting the quotes, etc. `putStrLn` instead of `putStr` adds a newline at the end.

Both of these will crash if the list returned by queens is empty. Safer variants include `listToMaybe`, case matches and/or the `forM`/`traverse` stuff from the other answer.

Comment: thanks for your help! However, I'm not really sure what to do with "print . drawQueens . head . queens :: Int -> IO ()"; I figured this is a function composition, but I don't know to what part of my code I should add this to. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: ghci, when given any value that is not of type IO a for some a, will plug it into print. Reading your "current output", I'll adjust my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this should work:

```
import Control.Monad

forM_ (map drawQueens (queens 8)) putStrLn
```

`forM_` "gives" each result in `drawQueens ...`  to `putStrLn`.

**Update**

`putStrLn` actually prints a String to the console thereby "interpreting" the new lines.

For example:

```
ghci> "line 1\nline 2\n"
"line 1\nline 2\n"
ghci> putStrLn "line 1\nline 2\n"
line 1
line 2
```

Comment: Thank you for your speedy answer! However this isn't quite what I'm looking for since I haven't really started working with Control.Monad. I guess my question lacked specification in that respect.

Comment: Found a few typos in my answer - updated with corrections.